# Hyperlinks click radius is bigger than the actual text

Tags: html, css

i have a website with some links on them, and the links are clickable for longer than the actual link.

[image]

As seen on the picture I am able to click the links way out to the right.

I tried searching for answers, but i didnt really know  how to formulate my answer, or just no answer seem to be there.

So is there a way that i can make the links to be the exact size of the text?

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  background-color: white;
  /* this breaks position sticky in Firefox */
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}
header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: #5D5C61;
  background-image: url("../Assets/Images/headerImage.jpg");
  color: white;
  padding: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Chivo';
  font-size: 22px;
}

header a {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #252E39;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Only stick if you can fit */
@media (min-height: 300px) {
  nav ul {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a.current {
  background: #51656E;
}

main {
    padding-top: -30px;
}

section {
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  
}

#section-1 {
    background-color: white;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: #37474F;
  padding: 5rem 1rem;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main a {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #6B7B83;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    color: #6B7B83;
}

.socialIcon {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

#socialMedia {
    text-align: center;
}



.CALink:hover {
    color: #202F36;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 30px;
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="icon" href="Assets/Images/faviconTTT.png"/>
        <title>Silverflame</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div id="socialMedia">
                <a href=""><img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/mark-github.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
                <img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/twitterSVG.svg"/>
            </div>

            <h1>SilverFlame</h1>
            <a target="headerLink" href="https://www..dk/">Home</a>
            <a target="headerLink" href="https://www..dk/CA.html">CA</a>  
            <a target="headerLink" href="">About</a>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#section-1">Studypoint exersice 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-2">Maven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-3">Network and HTTP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-4">JS and CA1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-5">MODUL 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-6">Section 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-7">Section 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-8">Section 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-9">Section 9</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main>
            
            <section id="section-1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div clasS="control-group">
                        <h1>Study Point Exercise 3 - JPA, JPQL and Testing </h1>
                        <h3>Part 1</h3>
                        <a href="https://github.com///tree/master">Exercise 
                        - JPA Entity Mappings - 1</a>
                        <a href="https://github.com///tree/master">Exercise 
                        - Java Persistence - Querying - 3</a>
                        <h3>Part 2</h3>     
                        <a href="#">Studypoint part two</a>
                        <h3>Part 3</h3>
                        <a href="https://github.com//ExamPrepOneJPQL">Exam Preparation 
                        Exercise on relations and queries</a>
                        <a href="https://github.com//ExamPrepTwoJPQL">Exam Preparation   
                        Exercise on JPQL</a>
                        <a href="#">Object Relational Mapping and Inheritance</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

        </main>
        </body>
```

Comment: Inside your ”a{}” you should try to add ”width:” like this: ”width: 50px;”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have those links set to `display: block` - you should set them to be `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`. Block level elements will automatically fill 100% of the available space horizontally.

See https://codeburst.io/block-level-and-inline-elements-the-difference-between-div-and-span-2f8502c1f95b

Edit: As someone commented, setting the links to be inline will cause them to appear on the same line. Put those links inside of some kind of wrapper (like a list `<ul>` with `<li>`s) and then the links inside of each list item.

Comment: But then they'll appear on the same line

Comment: I would update the markup to use an unordered list, which could be set to `display: block` so that they appear on their own lines, and then the links within can be inline.

Comment: Thank you Charlie !

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have the links set to display block, which will take up the width of the container. You can either make the link `display: table;`

```
main a {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: table;
}
```

Or put the links in a div container, leave the container as display:block; but make the links `display: inline-block;`

```
 <div class="link-container">
   <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/JPADayOneExercise/tree/master">Exercise 
                - JPA Entity Mappings - 1</a>
  </div>
```

css:

```
link-container a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set the anchors to `display: block` which will make them take up the full width of their container. You can remove that CSS rule and wrap your anchors in block elements like a div or paragraph to keep them on separate lines but not have the links be the full width.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  background-color: white;
  /* this breaks position sticky in Firefox */
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}

header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: #5D5C61;
  background-image: url("../Assets/Images/headerImage.jpg");
  color: white;
  padding: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Chivo';
  font-size: 22px;
}

header a {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #252E39;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Only stick if you can fit */

@media (min-height: 300px) {
  nav ul {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a.current {
  background: #51656E;
}

main {
  padding-top: -30px;
}

section {
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
}

#section-1 {
  background-color: white;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: #37474F;
  padding: 5rem 1rem;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

main a {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #6B7B83;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: #6B7B83;
}

.socialIcon {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

#socialMedia {
  text-align: center;
}

.CALink:hover {
  color: #202F36;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 30px;
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work Sans' rel='stylesheet'>


<header>
  <div id="socialMedia">
    <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005"><img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/mark-github.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
    <img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/twitterSVG.svg" />
  </div>

  <h1>SilverFlame</h1>
  <a target="headerLink" href="https://www.thesilverflame.dk/">Home</a>
  <a target="headerLink" href="https://www.thesilverflame.dk/CA.html">CA</a>
  <a target="headerLink" href="">About</a>
</header>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section-1">Studypoint exersice 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-2">Maven</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-3">Network and HTTP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-4">JS and CA1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-5">MODUL 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-6">Section 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-7">Section 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-8">Section 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-9">Section 9</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>

  <section id="section-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div clasS="control-group">
        <h1>Study Point Exercise 3 - JPA, JPQL and Testing </h1>
        <h3>Part 1</h3>
        <p><a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/JPADayOneExercise/tree/master">Exercise 
                        - JPA Entity Mappings - 1</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/JPADayTreeExercise/tree/master">Exercise 
                        - Java Persistence - Querying - 3</a></p>
        <h3>Part 2</h3>
        <a href="#">Studypoint part two</a>
        <h3>Part 3</h3>
        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/ExamPrepOneJPQL">Exam Preparation 
                        Exercise on relations and queries</a>
        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/ExamPrepTwoJPQL">Exam Preparation   
                        Exercise on JPQL</a>
        <a href="#">Object Relational Mapping and Inheritance</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `display: flex` for `.control-group` pointed in a columnar direction. To keep the links from expanding all the way out, use `align-self: flex-start;`. The advantage to using Flexbox here is that you don't need to add anything else to your markup.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  background-color: white;
  /* this breaks position sticky in Firefox */
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}
header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: #5D5C61;
  background-image: url("../Assets/Images/headerImage.jpg");
  color: white;
  padding: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Chivo';
  font-size: 22px;
}

header a {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #252E39;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Only stick if you can fit */
@media (min-height: 300px) {
  nav ul {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a.current {
  background: #51656E;
}

main {
    padding-top: -30px;
}

section {
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  
}

#section-1 {
    background-color: white;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: #37474F;
  padding: 5rem 1rem;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main a {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #6B7B83;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    color: #6B7B83;
}

.socialIcon {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

#socialMedia {
    text-align: center;
}



.CALink:hover {
    color: #202F36;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.control-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 30px;
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1%;
}

.control-group a {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="icon" href="Assets/Images/faviconTTT.png"/>
        <title>Silverflame</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div id="socialMedia">
                <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005"><img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/mark-github.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
                <img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/twitterSVG.svg"/>
            </div>

            <h1>SilverFlame</h1>
            <a target="headerLink" href="https://www.thesilverflame.dk/">Home</a>
            <a target="headerLink" href="https://www.thesilverflame.dk/CA.html">CA</a>  
            <a target="headerLink" href="">About</a>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#section-1">Studypoint exersice 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-2">Maven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-3">Network and HTTP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-4">JS and CA1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-5">MODUL 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-6">Section 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-7">Section 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-8">Section 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-9">Section 9</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main>
            
            <section id="section-1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div clasS="control-group">
                        <h1>Study Point Exercise 3 - JPA, JPQL and Testing </h1>
                        <h3>Part 1</h3>
                        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/JPADayOneExercise/tree/master">Exercise 
                        - JPA Entity Mappings - 1</a>
                        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/JPADayTreeExercise/tree/master">Exercise 
                        - Java Persistence - Querying - 3</a>
                        <h3>Part 2</h3>     
                        <a href="#">Studypoint part two</a>
                        <h3>Part 3</h3>
                        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/ExamPrepOneJPQL">Exam Preparation 
                        Exercise on relations and queries</a>
                        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/ExamPrepTwoJPQL">Exam Preparation   
                        Exercise on JPQL</a>
                        <a href="#">Object Relational Mapping and Inheritance</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

        </main>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change   display: block; to   display: inline-block; in

main a {
}

and add `</br>` after each line.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said, by using `display: block` on the links, it automatically makes them 100% width of the parent container.

I suggest you use `inline-block` instead. It's like a combination of `inline` and `block` (hence the name), but they won't be displayed horizontally like `inline` does, and it won't be 100% width like `block` does.

The best of both worlds!

Keep in mind though that the links clickable area will still be clickable beyond the text taking into consideration of padding (which extends the width).

So the new code would be:

```
nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  background-color: white;
  /* this breaks position sticky in Firefox */
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}
header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: #5D5C61;
  background-image: url("../Assets/Images/headerImage.jpg");
  color: white;
  padding: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Chivo';
  font-size: 22px;
}

header a {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #252E39;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Only stick if you can fit */
@media (min-height: 300px) {
  nav ul {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a.current {
  background: #51656E;
}

main {
    padding-top: -30px;
}

section {
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  
}

#section-1 {
    background-color: white;
}

footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background: #37474F;
  padding: 5rem 1rem;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

main a {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #6B7B83;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    color: #6B7B83;
}

.socialIcon {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

#socialMedia {
    text-align: center;
}



.CALink:hover {
    color: #202F36;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

.control-group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 30px;
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1%;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="icon" href="Assets/Images/faviconTTT.png"/>
        <title>Silverflame</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div id="socialMedia">
                <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005"><img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/mark-github.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
                <img class="socialIcon" src="Assets/Images/twitterSVG.svg"/>
            </div>

            <h1>SilverFlame</h1>
            <a target="headerLink" href="https://www.thesilverflame.dk/">Home</a>
            <a target="headerLink" href="https://www.thesilverflame.dk/CA.html">CA</a>  
            <a target="headerLink" href="">About</a>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#section-1">Studypoint exersice 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-2">Maven</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-3">Network and HTTP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-4">JS and CA1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-5">MODUL 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-6">Section 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-7">Section 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-8">Section 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-9">Section 9</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main>
            
            <section id="section-1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div clasS="control-group">
                        <h1>Study Point Exercise 3 - JPA, JPQL and Testing </h1>
                        <h3>Part 1</h3>
                        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/JPADayOneExercise/tree/master">Exercise 
                        - JPA Entity Mappings - 1</a>
                        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/JPADayTreeExercise/tree/master">Exercise 
                        - Java Persistence - Querying - 3</a>
                        <h3>Part 2</h3>     
                        <a href="#">Studypoint part two</a>
                        <h3>Part 3</h3>
                        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/ExamPrepOneJPQL">Exam Preparation 
                        Exercise on relations and queries</a>
                        <a href="https://github.com/jesper3005/ExamPrepTwoJPQL">Exam Preparation   
                        Exercise on JPQL</a>
                        <a href="#">Object Relational Mapping and Inheritance</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

        </main>
        </body>
```